# how can call javascript from c# ext.net

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, datetime, ext.net

in my project when i run it in chrome it is showing wrong time. explorer it is showing true. So i write this js code but it is still doesnt working. 
This is my js;

```js
  var FormatTrxStartDate = function (value, record) {
            var processDate = new Date(value);
            return processDate.getDate() + "." + (processDate.getMonth() + 1) + "." +
            processDate.getFullYear() + " " + processDate.getHours() + ":" +
            processDate.getMinutes() + ":" + processDate.getSeconds();
        };
```

And this is where i use it;

```
<ext:ModelField Name="TrxStartDate" Type="String" >
<Convert Fn='FormatTrxStartDate' />
</ext:ModelField>
```

Answer (score 2):

Pass Parameter Value in not proper Date Format

Use `processDate.getFullYear()==> processDate.getFullYear().toDateString()` date data convert into String

Comment: Thank you for ur answer but i couldnt see toDateString() it is just let me use toString() i tried it but doesnt work is is still looking wrong time. I mean normally time is; 
08:40
but when i use  google chrome it is looking 10:40

Answer (score 1):

```
X.Js.Call("FormatTrxStartDate ",value,record);
```

please try this code

Comment: chetan  thank you for ur answer. How can i use this code i dont understand clearly. Could u explain it please?

Comment: you can write this code in C# page and in that function from where you want to call this javascript

Comment: first parameter "ClientSideJavaScript" is something like title, you can write anything over there and in the second parameter write your function name of javascript.

Comment: thnk u. i try ur way but it is still doesnt working correctly.

Comment: Ext.Net.X.ResourceManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock("ClientSideJavaScript", "FormatTrxStartDate")

Comment: please try this, Just remove braces from the function.

Comment: Anybody can help me for solution?